# Can $(5^k+1)(2^k)$ be a perfect power?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, perfect-powers

Can $(5^k+1)(2^k)$ be a perfect power?

I noticed that $(5^k+1)(2^k)=(10^k+2^k)$, and this cannot be a perfect square since the last digit of $(5^k+1)(2^k)$ is either $2$, or $8$ when $k$ is odd, and when $k$ is even, it is equal to $2\pmod{3}$.

$(5^k+1)(2^k)$ is sometimes equal to $0,\pm1\pmod{9}$, so $(5^k+1)(2^k)$ maybe can be a perfect cube.

$(5^k+1)(2^k)$ can be only a perfect 5th power if the last 2 digits of the product is either $24, 64, 68,$ or $76$.

But $(5^k+1)(2^k)$ can be a higher perfect odd prime perfect power?

Using brute force, I tried to checked the values of $k\leq10^{4}$, but no number listed there is a perfect power.

Hint:$k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $(5^k+1)(2^k)=(10^k)+(2^k)$, so $2^{k+1}\mid(5^k+1)(2^k)$.

Comment: Why are you giving us a hint? Do you already have a proof of this?

Comment: @TonyK OP was probably given a hint (maybe in textbook or by someone).

Comment: @bb_823: that makes sense.

Comment: Maybe it helps that a necessary condition is that $\frac{5^k+1}{2}$ is a perfect power.

Comment: And this is not the case for any positive integer $k\le 10^5$

Comment: Since $5^k+1$ and $2^k$ are coprime, for their product to be a perfect $n$th power, both of them must individually be $n$th powers, so $5^k+1$ must be an $n$th power where $n \mid k$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang  Well, their gcd is exactly $2$.  Which is still useful.

Comment: This is equivalent to showing that the equation $5^{kl-1}+1=2y^l$ has no solutions in integers $k, l$ and $y$ with $l \geq 2$. There are ways to do this, but I can't see an easy, elementary approach.

Comment: Zsigmondy tells you that each of these numbers has a new prime factor. Unfortunately, this prime factor can be squared or cubed or anything else, so no dice.